# How do I stop the background image from stretching the last row and column of cells in my nested scrollable GridLayout?

Tags: android-studio, background-image, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

How to set background image on grid layout in android studio? This should be a simple problem, I might not search hard enough.

## What I want to achieve

I have a nested scrollable grid layout, and I want to programmatically fill in the cells while using a background image for the entrie grid layout.

Here is the xml code

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/map_background"> // BK image here

        </GridLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

I ignore the code for the cells but I can add it if anyone needs it. And here are the results.
[Cells with background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBMcM.png)

## What is the problem

The background image is too large, and the last column and row of cells stretch to the end.
[Problem cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8B9M.png)